# ffmpegthumbnailer error with carrierwave-video-thumbnailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, thumbnails, carrierwave

I am getting the error "No such file or directory" when I try to run ffmpegthumbnailer using the [carrierwave-video-thumbnailer gem](https://github.com/evrone/carrierwave-video-thumbnailer).

I confirmed that ffmpegthumbnailer is working correctly on my computer since I can generate a thumbnail image from a video straight from the command line.

From my logs, it looks like my app thinks that it has generated a thumbnail image.  However, when I look in the directory, there is no file tmpfile.png, and my app fails with the error.

**Has anyone successfully used the carrierewave-video-thumbnailer gem to create thumbnails, and if so, what am I doing wrong?**  Alternatively, if there is some way I can just run ffmpegthumbnailer within my model, I could do that too.

Here are my logs:

```
Running....ffmpegthumbnailer -i /Users/.../Website/public/uploads/tmp/1380315873-21590-2814/thumb_Untitled.mov -o /Users/.../Website/public/uploads/tmp/1380315873-21590-2814/tmpfile.png -c png -q 10 -s 192 -f
Success!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - (/Users/.../Website/public/uploads/tmp/1380315873-21590-2814/tmpfile.png, /Users/.../Website/public/uploads/tmp/1380315873-21590-2814/thumb_Untitled.mov)
```

**video_path_uploader.rb**

```
class VideoPathUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer

  process encode_video: [:mp4]

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   version :thumb do
      process thumbnail: [{format: 'png', quality: 10, size: 192, strip: true, logger: Rails.logger}]
      def full_filename for_file
        png_name for_file, version_name
      end
  end

    def png_name for_file, version_name
      %Q{#{version_name}_#{for_file.chomp(File.extname(for_file))}.png}
    end

end
```

**Video.rb**

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # maybe we should add a title attribute to the video?
  attr_accessible :position, :project_id, :step_id, :image_id, :saved, :embed_url, :thumbnail_url, :video_path
  mount_uploader :video_path, VideoPathUploader
...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was receiving the same error as you. It turned out that when the gem was attempting to run the **ffmpegthumbnailer** command it was failing because the input and output file paths contained spaces.

I fixed this by forking the gem and changing:

```
cmd = %Q{#{CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer::FFMpegThumbnailer.binary} -i #{input_path} -o #{output_path} #{options.to_cli}}.rstrip
```

to

```
cmd = %Q{#{CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer::FFMpegThumbnailer.binary} -i "#{input_path}" -o "#{output_path}" #{options.to_cli}}.rstrip
```

within the file:

```
lib/carrierwave/video/thumbnailer/ffmpegthumbnailer.rb
```

i.e. I surrounded the 'input_path' and 'output_path' arguments with double quotes.

This fixed the issue for me and the png thumbnail was successfully generated in the same directory as the original movie file. For reference I was generating a thumbnail image for a .mov quicktime file uploaded using a multipart form.

I was using **carrierwave-video-thumbnailer-0.1.4**

Comment: Thanks - it was an issue with the spacing as you suggested!